# Can the roots of a quadratic equation ever be a square root plus another square root?

Tags: roots, quadratics, algebraic-numbers

Can one of the roots of a quadratic equation ever be of the form $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$? Assuming $x$ and $y$ are not perfect squares.

The coefficients and constant of the quadratic equation need to be integers. I'm looking to see if $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ can ever be an algebraic number of degree 2.

Comment: How about $x^2-18$ which has $\sqrt2+\sqrt{8}$ as a root?

Comment: Wouldn't the roots of $x^2 - 18$ be $\pm \sqrt{18}$?

Comment: @KenMueller:  Yes, but $\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt 2=\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 8$

Comment: @RossMillikan wow, didn't know that

Comment: "I'm looking to see if x−−√+y√ can ever be an algebraic number."  They can't be.  No combination of radicals and nested radicals can be.  You can always work backwords.

Comment: If $(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})= (x+y) + 2\sqrt{xy}$ so if $xy$ is a perfect square this will always work.  $\sqrt{12} + \sqrt{27} =\sqrt{75}$.  Might be different if require $\gcd(x,y) = 1$.

Comment: "I'm looking to see if x−−√+y√ can ever be an algebraic number of degree 2"  You keep moving the goalposts.  But lord sark showed you they could way back at the begining with $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{8} = \sqrt{18}$  Perhaps a question would be *must* they be the root of a quadratic.  I'm pretty sure they don't have to be (although they do have to be the roots of quartic) but someone else can verify if I'm correct.

Comment: Yes $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{8}$ is a valid answer to my question!

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to construct.
$$
p(z) = (z-(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}))(z-a)
$$
is such a polynomial for any $a$. You can put any $x$ and $y$ you like in there.

Perhaps you want to ask the question with more restrictions.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to include that the coefficients and constant of the quadratic equation need to be integers. Looking to see if $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ can ever be an algebraic number.

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are rational, $\sqrt x+\sqrt y$ is an algebraic number. Algebraic numbers form a field. @KenMueller

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, but is it an algebraic number of degree 2?

Comment: If $\sqrt x + \sqrt y$ is not the root of a quadratic, it will be the root of a quartic.  So it will never be algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just work backwards and force it.

$x = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{11}$

$x^2  = 3 + 2\sqrt{33} + 11 = 14 +2\sqrt{33}$

$x^2 -14 = 2\sqrt{33}$

$(x^2 - 14)^2 = 4*33$

$x^4 - 28x^2 + 14^2 = 132$

$x^4 - 28x^2 + 64=0$ has $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{11}$ as one of its roots.  ... which one wouldn't think by looking at it.

.....

Or in general $x = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$

$w^2 = x + y + 2\sqrt{xy}$

$(w^2 - (x+y))^2 = 4xy$

$w^4 -2(x+y)w^2 + (x^2 - 2xy + y^2)=0$

$w^4 - 2(x+y)w^2 + (x-y)^2= 0$.

Hey, that's kind of nicely symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include an additional constraint, updated my question

Comment: "Sorry, I forgot to include an additional constraint, updated my question"  ?????  You haven't included anything I haven't considered.  Obviously you want integer coefficients and you want true radicals....

Comment: Oh, you said quadraditic.